# few lines insert in existing file via terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, terminator

i have file test.txt

```
hi
hello
good luck
```

i want in this test.txt

```
hi
hello
good luck
lms
localhost
```

how to add last two lines in terminal command
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
echo -e "lms\nlocalhost" >> test.txt
```

`\n` is for a new line.

`>>` redirects output to a file and appends it to the end of the file.

`-e` is to parse control characters like `\n`.